# Grunt build is breaking my compiled javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I've got a project that wasn't mine from the beginning and the whole deployment was incomplete. I have the freaking grunt ignoring overrides specified [here](https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer/issues/33#issuecomment-127979949) and now i've discovered that when he generates the *vendor.js* with all the dependencies it simply doesn't work. The browser prints:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:14(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:14
vendor.js:4 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'gettext' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/nomod?p0=gettext(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:4(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:4b @ vendor.js:4l.bootstrap @ vendor.js:4(anonymous function) @ scripts.js:1
VM47 vendor.js:4 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module trepeatApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularPayments due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularPayments' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

When i'm using just the *grunt serve* task it works fine but if i *grunt build* something in these tasks bellow just breaks the freaking script

```
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin',
```

Can someone help me? I'm getting quite desperate

[UPDATE - 24/08/2015]
I've read the link the @RobSchmuecker comment and changed some stuff on `gettext` config and one of the errors was solved.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module trepeatApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularPayments due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularPayments' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/nomod?p0=angularPayments
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:15152
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:24650
    at b (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:24123)
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:24435
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1222
    at f (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:15559)
    at n (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1000)
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1169
    at f (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:15559)
    at n (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1000)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularPayments&p1=…20n%20(http%3A%2F%2Fmylocaldev.com%3A3000%2Fscripts%2Fvendor.js%3A5%3A1000)
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:15152
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1428
    at f (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:15559)
    at n (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1000)
    at http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1169
    at f (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:15559)
    at n (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:1000)
    at $a (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:5:2690)
    at h (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:22195)
    at ga (http://mylocaldev.com:3000/scripts/vendor.js:4:22505)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=trepeatApp&p1=Error…ga%20(http%3A%2F%2Fmylocaldev.com%3A3000%2Fscripts%2Fvendor.js%3A4%3A22505)
```

Comment: It gives you error details, so go and check usage of `Item` and `gettext`, how they are injected, minification safe or not, etc.

Comment: You are probably not defining and injecting the `angularPayments` module correctly to allow the minifier to correctly reference it.  Have a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: I already know what caused the `Item`, grunt ignoring overrides specified like i've said on the question @dfsq

Comment: I'm going to check that link @RobSchmuecker. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that when i ran `grunt serve` everything would work fine but when i compiled, minified and everything else this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:14(anonymous function) @ vendor.js:14`

Would actually prevent the proper functioning of angular. This problem is caused because the freaking `outlayer` needs to be overriden on the `bower.json` file so that the `item.js` is loaded before the `outlayer.js` and for some unknown reason the overrides option is not working for me. I've had to remove the `outlayer` from my `bower.json`and include it manually on the index after everything was loaded on angular.

Answer (score 0):

As jesus.jackson.sena correctly states, this error can be caused by Outlayer. But in contrast to him, overrides works well for me. So as a reference for those who need it, that's how to set the override correctly in `bower.json`:

```
"overrides": {
  "outlayer": {
    "main": [
      "item.js",
      "outlayer.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

For those interested in the reason for this behaviour:
`outlayer.js` has the following initialization code:

```
window.Outlayer = factory(
  window,
  window.EvEmitter,
  window.getSize,
  window.fizzyUIUtils,
  window.Outlayer.Item
);
```

For window.Outlayer.Item to be defined, Outlayer's item.js has to be called first, which defines it as follows:

```
window.Outlayer = {};
window.Outlayer.Item = factory(
  window.EvEmitter,
  window.getSize
);
```